# Setting up an HTTPS proxy

Tags: wi-fi, 4.3-jelly-bean, proxy, https

I use proxifier to connect to an HTTPS proxy on the PC, what should I do in order to connect similarly on my Android smartphone?

My Android version is 4.3, Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

Use Drony. You change type in settings from default http to https. Be careful about HTTPS proxy certificate. If it's self signed there is option to trust all certs in settings. But then you can have mitm so it's not very secure. 
There is nice blog about setting up whole configuration. 
http://blog.habets.pp.se/2014/09/Secure-browser-to-proxy-communication---again

by Drony support

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting over Wi-Fi, and are concerned only about connections from Chrome and not from other applications, then you don't need any third-party software to redirect HTTP and HTTPS connections to a proxy.  Just go into the Wi-Fi settings, find your network, long-press on it, choose Modify Network, show advanced options, and set the proxy there.

Whether this gets used by non-Chrome applications depends on the application.  You could try it and see if your applications honour it.